# Bring User of Mobile App to Checkout View of a 3rd Party Web-Store With Some Products in His Basket

Tags: android, nginx, networking

I'm building an Android prototype for the following use case

- User selects a recipe in mobile app
- Button: `[Buy at <Store>]` appears
- User clicks on the button
- User gets redirected to store with all the ingredients in his basket

Unfortunately I can't just use custom tabs because there is no way of setting a cookie from inside the application.

I wasn't able to make a get request with what looks like a session-cookie.

Tried using [mtmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy) to check out the traffic of the stores' mobile application. This won't work without a workaround on phones with Android Version 7 or later, as discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/2054).

So, I'm running a HTTP Tunnel on NGINX with the [ngx_http_proxy_connect module](https://github.com/chobits/ngx_http_proxy_connect_module) and in order to establish a connection I'd have to use the connect method. The Problem with that is the Android documentation states that the Connect method is forbidden for the HttpURLConnection in Java class.
Does that mean I have to create TCP sockets and the question is how do I establish a secure connection  using the tunnel?

Haven't done any of this before and I'm learning a lot. But I don't have the foresight to figure out
if what I'm doing is technically/legally/ethically correct. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Cant you generate a token and itemId then make a post request to store via WebView then process these details on the website?

Comment: @tendai I'm not sure what you mean by "process these details on the website" - I don't run the store. Simply using webview was my first attempt. But any link the user is going to click will open up the browser without the cookies.